# funnelweb IndexError

Tags: plone, plone-funnelweb

I am trying to upload imported pages to plone using funnelweb. I have made a few posts regarding funnelweb, I guess I could mail the creators of the add-on to help solve this problem, but I think that others might need help with the same particular problem. Therefor it is more useful for everyone if the post is public, and not through mail :-)

Now to my problem. To upload the imported pages to plone, I have typed:

```
bin/funnelweb ploneupload:target://admin:password@localhost:8080/Wiki
```

I get the follwing error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/funnelweb", line 116, in <module>
    mr.migrator.runner.runner({},"funnelweb.remote")
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/mr.migrator-1.0.1-py2.7.egg/mr/migrator/runner/__init__.py", line 132, in runner
    transmogrifier(pipelineid, **overrides)
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.transmogrifier-1.3-py2.7.egg/collective/transmogrifier/transmogrifier.py", line 59, in __call__
    pipeline = constructPipeline(self, sections)       
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.transmogrifier-1.3-py2.7.egg/collective/transmogrifier/utils.py", line 52, in constructPipeline
    pipeline)
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transmogrify.webcrawler-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/transmogrify/webcrawler/webcrawler.py", line 169, in __init__
    if self.site_url[-1] != '/':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Any suggestion about how to solve this? I guess it's a bug.

Does this add-on have a lot of bugs, or is it just that it doesn't do well with the newer version of plone?

Comment: You need 50 reputation points to be able to comment on *other* questions or answers; you can always comment on your own question, and and any answers given to that. There should be a `Add Comment` box below each answer.

Comment: If you have questions about how Stack Overflow works, you can ask those on [meta] (but do search fist).

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify a *source* to funnel *from*. The error is thrown because there is no site url to crawl and upload.

Try:

```
bin/funnelweb --crawler:url=http://wiki.scandiatransplant.com --crawler:max=50 --ploneupload:target=http://admin:admin@localhost:8080/TestPage
```

Comment: That is what I tried at start, but it complains about "--ploneupload" not beeing a valid option. What I tried I found on the page: http://plone.org/products/funnelweb, which is seen about half way of page. It says: Uploading happens via remote XML-RPC calls so can be done to a live running site anywhere.

To set where a the site will be uploaded to use: $> bin/funnelweb --ploneupload:target=http://username:password@myhost.com/myfolder                              .I have crawled the page, it is under the var folder, but I want it to be uploaded to my plone page under the folder called "Wiki"

Comment: Previously you had forgotten the `:target` part. Did you test *with* that part now?

Comment: Yeah. But I made it work finally. If I do --ploneupload, it doesn't work, but if I ommit the "--", and do just "ploneupload", it works. So this is what I typed: bin/funnelweb --crawler:url=http://wiki.scandiatransplant.org ploneupload:target=http://admin:password@localhost:8080/Plone. Now I just need to find out how to upload it to a folder, cus the above creates a new tab for each html page. And also, the links are broken.

Comment: Also, it doesn't import the .pdf or images. I noticed the the user can choose to ignore certain files by using regular expression, but I did not choose to ignore the pdf or images. Have tried to import images or pdf files?

Comment: @user1960836: That doesn't make sense` the `--ploneupload` part is a *prefix*; you need to add option names after it. `ploneupload` is the step name, and the `target` is an argument for that step. See http://plone.org/products/funnelweb/#commandline-arguments and http://plone.org/products/funnelweb/#configuration-options. Any argument without a `:` in it is actually completely ignored. So just specifying `ploneupload` means it ignores that part completely. You do need to add `http://` in front of your URLs, and most of all, read the documentation carefully. :-)

Comment: @user1960836: Also, the `--` is completely optional. If it worked with the `--` removed, then you changed something else as well.

Comment: The documentation and examples used http:// in front of the urls, so I thought it was required.
Strange this doesn't make sense: bin/funnelweb --crawler:url=wiki.scandiatransplant.org ploneupload:target=admin:password@localhost:8080/Plone. That is what I did, and it did work.

Comment: Does anyone know how to import to a specific folder? I have a folder called "Wiki" on my Plone site, and I want to import everything to that folder. If I do: bin/funnelweb --crawler:url=http://wiki.scandiatransplant.org --crawler:max=200 ploneupload:target=http://admin:code@localhost:7070/Scandiatransplant/Wiki, I get an error, but if I ommit the "Wiki" and just do: bin/funnelweb --crawler:url=http://wiki.scandiatransplant.org --crawler:max=200 ploneupload:target=http://admin:code@localhost:7070/Scandiatransplant, then it imports, but it creates each page as a tab. It looks all messed up

Comment: And also, it doesn't import the images and pdf files. If I look in the var folder, where the imported pages/files are placed, the images ad pdf files are there, but it just doesn't upload it to plone. I can't find anywhere in the documentation that says that images and other files should be imported differently. Am I missing something?